# How apply to SHA to my RSA encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, sha, python-3.5

I am working on in python learning how to encrypt messages using RSA and SHA. I have written the RSA code and and working on implementing the SHA code into the program correctly so that that my messages and first encrypted using the RSA and then hashed using the SHA. Have a look and let me know what you think. Thanks.

```
                # RSA Cipher
            # http://inventwithpython.com/hacking (BSD Licensed)

            import sys, os
            import hashlib
            # IMPORTANT: The block size MUST be less than or equal to the key size!
            # (Note: The block size is in bytes, the key size is in bits. There
            # are 8 bits in 1 byte.)
            DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE = 128 # 128 bytes
            BYTE_SIZE = 256 # One byte has 256 different values.

            def main():
                # Runs a test that encrypts a message to a file or decrypts a message
                # from a file.
                filename = 'encrypted_file.txt' # the file to write to/read from
                eord = "encrypt or decrypt?"
                mode = (input(eord)) # set to 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'
                secure = 'Please enter public key'
                ath = eval(input(secure))
                if mode == 'encrypt':
                    if ath == 615:
                        message = input('What is your message?')
                        pubKeyFilename = 'al_sweigart_pubkey.txt'

                        print('Encrypting and writing to %s...' % (filename))
                        encryptedText = encryptAndWriteToFile(filename, pubKeyFilename, message)
                        mystring = filename
                        # Assumes the default UTF-8
                        hash_object = hashlib.md5(mystring.encode())
                        print('Encrypted text:')
                        print(encryptedText)
                    else:
                        print('incorrect public key try again')
                elif mode == 'decrypt':
                    privKeyFilename = 'al_sweigart_privkey.txt'
                    print('Reading from %s and decrypting...' % (filename))
                    decryptedText = readFromFileAndDecrypt(filename, privKeyFilename)

                    print('Decrypted text:')
                    print(decryptedText)


            def getBlocksFromText(message, blockSize=DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE):
                # Converts a string message to a list of block integers. Each integer
                # represents 128 (or whatever blockSize is set to) string characters.

                messageBytes = message.encode('ascii') # convert the string to bytes

                blockInts = []
                for blockStart in range(0, len(messageBytes), blockSize):
                    # Calculate the block integer for this block of text
                    blockInt = 0
                    for i in range(blockStart, min(blockStart + blockSize, len(messageBytes))):
                        blockInt += messageBytes[i] * (BYTE_SIZE ** (i % blockSize))
                    blockInts.append(blockInt)
                return blockInts


            def getTextFromBlocks(blockInts, messageLength, blockSize=DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE):
                # Converts a list of block integers to the original message string.
                # The original message length is needed to properly convert the last
                # block integer.
                message = []
                for blockInt in blockInts:
                    blockMessage = []
                    for i in range(blockSize - 1, -1, -1):
                        if len(message) + i < messageLength:
                            # Decode the message string for the 128 (or whatever
                            # blockSize is set to) characters from this block integer.
                            asciiNumber = blockInt // (BYTE_SIZE ** i)
                            blockInt = blockInt % (BYTE_SIZE ** i)
                            blockMessage.insert(0, chr(asciiNumber))
                    message.extend(blockMessage)
                return ''.join(message)


            def encryptMessage(message, key, blockSize=DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE):
                # Converts the message string into a list of block integers, and then
                # encrypts each block integer. Pass the PUBLIC key to encrypt.
                encryptedBlocks = []
                n, e = key

                for block in getBlocksFromText(message, blockSize):
                    # ciphertext = plaintext ^ e mod n
                    encryptedBlocks.append(pow(block, e, n))
                return encryptedBlocks


            def decryptMessage(encryptedBlocks, messageLength, key, blockSize=DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE):
                # Decrypts a list of encrypted block ints into the original message
                # string. The original message length is required to properly decrypt
                # the last block. Be sure to pass the PRIVATE key to decrypt.
                decryptedBlocks = []
                n, d = key
                for block in encryptedBlocks:
                    # plaintext = ciphertext ^ d mod n
                    decryptedBlocks.append(pow(block, d, n))
                return getTextFromBlocks(decryptedBlocks, messageLength, blockSize)


            def readKeyFile(keyFilename):
                # Given the filename of a file that contains a public or private key,
                # return the key as a (n,e) or (n,d) tuple value.
                fo = open(keyFilename)
                content = fo.read()
                fo.close()
                keySize, n, EorD = content.split(',')
                return (int(keySize), int(n), int(EorD))


            def encryptAndWriteToFile(messageFilename, keyFilename, message, blockSize=DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE):
                # Using a key from a key file, encrypt the message and save it to a
                # file. Returns the encrypted message string.
                keySize, n, e = readKeyFile(keyFilename)

                # Check that key size is greater than block size.
                if keySize < blockSize * 8: # * 8 to convert bytes to bits
                    sys.exit('ERROR: Block size is %s bits and key size is %s bits. The RSA cipher requires the block size to be equal to or greater than the key size. Either decrease the block size or use different keys.' % (blockSize * 8, keySize))


                # Encrypt the message
                encryptedBlocks = encryptMessage(message, (n, e), blockSize)

                # Convert the large int values to one string value.
                for i in range(len(encryptedBlocks)):
                    encryptedBlocks[i] = str(encryptedBlocks[i])
                encryptedContent = ','.join(encryptedBlocks)

                # Write out the encrypted string to the output file.
                encryptedContent = '%s_%s_%s' % (len(message), blockSize, encryptedContent)
                fo = open(messageFilename, 'w')
                fo.write(encryptedContent)
                fo.close()
                # Also return the encrypted string.
                return encryptedContent


            def readFromFileAndDecrypt(messageFilename, keyFilename):
                # Using a key from a key file, read an encrypted message from a file
                # and then decrypt it. Returns the decrypted message string.
                keySize, n, d = readKeyFile(keyFilename)


                # Read in the message length and the encrypted message from the file.
                fo = open(messageFilename)
                content = fo.read()
                messageLength, blockSize, encryptedMessage = content.split('_')
                messageLength = int(messageLength)
                blockSize = int(blockSize)

                # Check that key size is greater than block size.
                if keySize < blockSize * 8: # * 8 to convert bytes to bits
                    sys.exit('ERROR: Block size is %s bits and key size is %s bits. The RSA cipher requires the block size to be equal to or greater than the key size. Did you specify the correct key file and encrypted file?' % (blockSize * 8, keySize))

                # Convert the encrypted message into large int values.
                encryptedBlocks = []
                for block in encryptedMessage.split(','):
                    encryptedBlocks.append(int(block))

                # Decrypt the large int values.
                return decryptMessage(encryptedBlocks, messageLength, (n, d), blockSize)


            # If rsaCipher.py is run (instead of imported as a module) call
            # the main() function.
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                main()
```

Comment: Why would you apply SHA1 to an RSA ciphertext? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This RSA code is very insecure, because it doesn't implement padding. Such textbook RSA should not be used for anything. Implement OAEP or at the very least PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am working on a project to encrypt messages and have user authentication so that messages can be sent over a cloud network securely.

Comment: Ok, that's what RSA is for. It provides confidentiality, but what do you need SHA1 for?

Comment: well my professor wanted to combine RSA with MD5 for a hybrid encryption originally but as I read about the MD5/RSA hybrid I read that the hybrid it wasn't that good because of too many collisions on the MD5's part. so i was seeing would SHA be a better replacement for MD5

Comment: [Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) makes sense with a symmetric cipher like AES-CBC. The problem is that SHA1 is a hashing algorithm and not a cipher, so hybrid encryption doesn't make much sense. I ask again, can you describe what it would be used for and how? You could start by describing how RSA+MD5 would have been used.